# Intution about the memoryless property of geometric distribution

Tags: distributions, intuition, geometric-distribution

I was watching the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-UFi4T3w7c) about the memoryless property of geometric distribution. Here is an excerpt from the video.

> $$\begin{aligned} P(X \geq x+y \mid X \geq x) &=\frac{P(X \geq x+y, X  \geq x)}{P(X \geq x)} \\ &=\frac{P(X \geq x+y)}{P(X \geq x)} \\  &=\frac{(1-p)^{x+y}}{(1-p)^{x}} \\ &=(1-p)^{y} \\ &=P(X \geq y) \end{aligned} $$

He mentions an example. In which there is a trial that follows a geometric distribution. After the 3rd trial without success someone else comes in and starts to observe the same trial.

What I don't understand is as follows: That new coming person will have a different interpretation of the events. He/She will have a geometric distribution starting from scratch leading to a different probability for the same event compared to the person who started it in the first place.

For the first observer $P(X \geq x+y \mid X \geq x) = (X \geq 3+y \mid X \geq 3) = P(X \geq y) $. Let's say $y=1$. So this means $P(X \geq 4 \mid X \geq 3) = P(X \geq 1) $ . However, for my understanding, $P(X \geq 1)$ is the probability that the second observer will use.

Or can I interprete this as the first observer (kind of) becomes a new observer in each time step and actually invalidates the assumption of the geometric distribution that he made one step(or more steps) ago? I mean, is it ok to say that the trial will have success with $(1-p)^np$ probability at $n$th step before everything started, but when you are at $n-1$ step you actually have a different distribution from that time onwards?

This memoryless property seems trivial at first sight but I got lost when I tried to really grasp it. I appreciate the intuitive explanations rather than just mathematical formulas.

Comment: After watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuqLI4otMIQ, I assume my interpretation is right. I will leave the question not deleted in case other people can have a similar confusion.

Comment: The memoryless property means that knowing previous outcome will not affect the probabilities of future outcome. In a sense your system has no memory of the previous outcome because it does affect the future outcome.
In your example, the fact that "X will increase by one" is the same no matter how many outcome have been observed before.